# Do generics in Java avoid all ClassCastExceptins?

Tags: java, generics, java-6, classcastexception

Since generics are only checked during compile time with Java 5,  can they avoid ClassCastExceptions in all
situations?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

First of all, you should make sure that your code compiles without unckeched warnings. That is a good indicator. To understand why, I suggest you take a look at the [sample chapter for generics from Effective Java](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/effective/).

Second of all, generics can't guard you from code such as:

```
public void methodOne(Integer argument)  {
     methodTwo(argument);
} 

public void methodTwo(Object argument) {
     System.out.println(((Date) argument).getTime());
}
```

Third of all, if you're in some way or another messing with Class Loaders, you might get strange `ClassCastExceptions`, such as in [this discussion thread](http://www.techienuggets.com/Comments?tx=5498). It is mind-numbing to see

> java.lang.ClassCastException: javax.mail.Session cannot be cast to 
>   javax.mail.Session

So the answer is *no, you can't get rid of `ClassCastException`s just by properly using generics*.

Answer (score 16):

The "cast-iron" guarantee that Java 5 generics provides is that you will never see a ClassCastException from the casts inserted by the compiler *provided* that compilation produced no "unchecked" warnings.

In real life, you often can't avoid unchecked warnings if your code uses legacy (non-generified) libraries.  Then the compiler-generated casts *can* throw ClassCastException, and it's your job to prevent this by ensuring that the values returned by library code are well-typed for your declarations.

Otherwise the situation is unchanged.  Outside of generics, if you cast to an incompatible type you'll get a ClassCastException the same way as you always did.

(A good reference for this and other generics questions is [Java Generics and Collections](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596527754/).)

Answer (score 2):

No. Using Java 5.0 and generics type doesn't make you ClassCastException-proof.

Comment: If you don't cast at all, you shouldn't see any ClassCastException.

Answer (score -1):

Nope.  generics only save you from compile time errors, not runtime exceptions.